# Designing for dynamic layout seen in ERP/ complex configurable systems

Tags: website-design, gui-design, conventions

This is what I am trying to achieve.

How can I make such a design in web application using ASP.NET properly.

[image]

A bit of thought on the same:-

1. How to properly set this up with good layout manager?
2. Template is dynamic and is generated based on the database values. Template will have only table rows and columns and the content is to be dynamically created (labels/textboxes/checkboxes)
3. Is creating user controls for each template a better approach?

Can I have inputs from people who have designed this kind of complex systems? Say equivalent of ERP where every part in website is configurable..

PS: The topic was moved from Programmers to UX for a better input. Please don't close it as offtopic.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing what the UX question is here. A number of things you are asking are very much offtopic. Can you be more specific with your question, and make it more directly related to UX?

Comment: I don't understand what "this" is. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some kind of 'widget' technology - make widget module for each template and compose widgets (portlets, etc.) to a kind of dashboard. There are a lot of components to implement this. A few samples:

- http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets
- http://eksith.com/experiments/dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

Well, the typical modern way to do this is by creating widgets. Every widget can be configured  with its parameters, but is designed as an isolated piece. Then you have pages with any series of widgets distributed in a user customized way. Examples of this is the old Google customizable dashboard.